# SQL query in one row one value and changing it's value in another row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a small problem and i trying to solve it from yesterday.
When user signup, in signup page there is also a "Sponsor" field, username of one who invited him on the site.
I'm giving some bonus to that sponsor for every verified referral. When user confirm email script for verification will run, he will be activated and sponsor should receive some bonus.
This is the part of script that have job to do that.

```
if($status=="OK")
{
//updating status if validation passes
$rec1=mysql_query("select referedby from affiliateuser where email=$email");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($rec1);
$ref=$row2[0];
$query4=mysql_query(" update affiliateuser set active = 1 where email = '$email'");
$query3=mysql_query(" update affiliateuser set tamount = tamount + 5 where username = '$ref'");
$query4=mysql_query(" update affiliateuser set tamount = 49 where username = '$username'");
echo "<center><p>Thank You For Signing Up With Us.<br/>You Are Now Verified Member. You May Now Login Into Website. </p></center>";
}
```

So if everything is okay it will select sponsor's username from this user, $query3 should then update row of sponsor and change his balance(tamount) but his balance is untouched. I was put some of those lines of code to say error if something is wrong with this and it say error.
I'm first time trying something like this with two rows and it's very possible that i wrote something wrong.
How can i solve this, it's there any other way. Currently i don't care about sql injection etc, just want to fix this, thanks.

Comment: You're using the prehistoric `mysql_*` library and your code is at serious risk for sql injection - do yourself a favor and read a tutorial about prepared statements and PDO

Comment: Well you may not care about SQL injection, the SQL injection issue is also why this `where email=$email` is invalid SQL. You also can do this all in 2 queries.

Comment: Yes, but can they know what i'm using? Links are not injectable.

Comment: @LazarBiz They can't know, but they can try some basic kiddy script attempts to hack your website using common sql injection techniques - Passing dangerous input to the server from a form on your website for example ([Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). Best way to deal with it is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)  where instead of you escaing the string in your query, you use "placeholders" and assing them the actual values - Safe and easy

Comment: Ok, i understand. I will try to learn at least some basic of pdo or sqli. Protection is also important for me, but for now is okay. Thank you very much for your time. Still have to learn a lot.

Comment: @LazarBiz Glad to help :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget the difference between the ' and " ,

```
if($status=="OK")
{
//updating status if validation passes
$rec1=mysql_query("select referedby from affiliateuser where email='".$email."'");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($rec1);
$ref=$row2[0];
$query4=mysql_query(" update affiliateuser set active = 1 where email = '".$email."'");
$query3=mysql_query(" update affiliateuser set tamount = tamount + 5 where username = '".$ref."'");
$query4=mysql_query(" update affiliateuser set tamount = 49 where username = '".$username."'");
echo "<center><p>Thank You For Signing Up With Us.<br/>You Are Now Verified Member. You May Now Login Into Website. </p></center>";
}
```

try this

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm really beginner and i use many instructions from some sites,blogs,stackovoerflow etc.. and it's very possible that i used wrong one :) Thank you again.

Comment: @LazarBiz as a beginner you should not start with `mysql_`. It will fail you very soon. Use `pdo`, or `mysqli`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to convert all mysql in code to mysqli. I will try looking, but important think is that it works.